# how to achieve RandStream.getDefaultStream in matlab2014a

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to reproduce some random data generation. I was given some old matlab code.

```
defaultStream = RandStream.getDefaultStream;
savedState = defaultStream.State;
s = RandStream.create('mt19937ar','seed',seed);
RandStream.setDefaultStream(s);
```

After this code block, randperm was called in a loop.

Matlab 2014a do not have getDefaultStream for RandStream anymore. Is there any 2014a equivalence to the code above? I would like to be able to generate the same data as was done before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those were renamed `RandStream.getGlobalStream` and `RandStream.setGlobalStream`.

Also now there is `rng` which is easier to use.